# Is it possible to set an image or xib as value in textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

As title stated, I wish to put an image or xib as value in my textfield. This is my design:

[image: Design]

For the 3 black dots I can achieve by using placeholder, but how about the first textfield that has a value? I need to set a round purple, with a border, and it as to be value of the textfield, which means user can delete it and edit the textfield.

I have tried doing something like this :

```
let imageView = UIImageView();
let image = UIImage(named: "dot-icon");
imageView.image = image;
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
tfTest.addSubview(imageView)
let leftView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
tfTest.leftView = leftView;
tfTest.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
```

This can achieve what I want by adding an image to the textfield, but now the textfield is not editable.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: FYI - it's much simpler to have a single, off-screen `UITextField` that the user types into and you use its value as it changes to update your image views as needed.

Comment: What do you mean by off-screen UITextField

Comment: Set the frame of the text field so the text field is not visible within the bounds of the view controller. Something like `CGRect(x: -100, y: -100, width: 100, height: 40)`. Use it just like a normal text field but just out of view.

Comment: OK. So can I do something like this  1. i have what you said in my screen  2. I make the tf first responder in viewdidload  3. I update image view as the text changes  4. I resign first responder when text reaches 4 digits  5. Make tf first responder when user tap on the image view

Comment: what do you mean xib?? You can add subview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take 4 imageView [pinImgView1, pinImgView2, pinImgView3, pinImgView4]

and one TextField [pinTextField].

deleget method:

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")
        if (string.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) == nil && string.characters.count > 0)
        {
            return false
        }

        let newString = (self.pinTextField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
        self.showPinImagesAsPerString(stringPIN: newString as String)
        return true
    }
```

Then add this methods:

```
    @objc func clearTextField()
    {
        self.pinTextField.text = ""
        self.pinImgView1.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_black")
        self.pinImgView2.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_black")
        self.pinImgView3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_black")
        self.pinImgView4.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_black")
        self.pinTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func showPinImagesAsPerString(stringPIN: String)
    {
        let length = stringPIN.characters.count
        self.pinImgView1.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_black")
        self.pinImgView2.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_black")
        self.pinImgView3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_black")
        self.pinImgView4.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_black")

        if length > 0{
            self.pinImgView1.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_Purple")
        }
        if length > 1{
            self.pinImgView2.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_Purple")
        }
        if length > 2{
            self.pinImgView3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_Purple")
        }
        if length > 3{

            self.pinImgView4.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_Purple")

          //here you need to check entered PIN (stringPIN) is correct or not

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me solved my question along with other comments

Comment: yehhh!! @user3051673